# VMRC console has disconnected ...I'm tired of uninstalling and re-installing the entire client

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, esxi, vsphere

Don't have vCenter Server so we administer ESXi 6 hosts via the vSphere client.

Often from some Windows machines we can't get to the VM consoles due to the error in the console window reading:

"The VMRC console has disconnected ...attempting to reconnect."

Occasionally re-starting vSphere client corrects it, if that won't do it then re-booting the windows machine running the client will, if that won't do it then uninstalling and re-installing the client works.

Uninstalling and re-installing takes a long time and I'd much prefer to fix it vs. fight it.

Anybody get to the bottom of this?  Is it an AV or Windows firewall issue, if so why would it be intermittent?

Thanks all,

Comment: -I seem to have reached a point where even re-installation won't work.  Can't get a console at all and have reverted to a backup admin system.. I've downloaded the latest version of vsphere client 6.0.0, uninstalled anything and everything from vmware on the PC and tried starting with just the new rev as admin, etc, etc.  Not sure what to try next, re-installing windows I suppose.

Comment: This seems like a technical support issue that would be answered better on the VMware community forums (be sure to post your VMRC log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was related to the IE plugin.  I found a reference here: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/456132 that said to replace the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\VMware\VMware Remote Console Plug-in 5.5\Internet Explorer` directory with a copy from a system with normal VMRC behavior.  A similar clue was to be sure that IE could reach the host.  I realized that IE may never have been launched after recent windows updates so I started up IE (I don't otherwise use IE) and it wanted me to buy off on standard security rules which I did and then I directed it at the hosts IP and bought off the https warning which took me to the hosts welcome webpage.  At this point I opened vsphere client, connected to the host as normal only now the Consoles all work and no VMRC erros have occurred.  To be clear I never replaced the plugin directory, it was replaced automatically each time I re-installed.  All I did was touch IE and visit the hosts page to get consoles working again!